# Configure Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, reverse-proxy, port-forwarding

I have setup a Linux AMI Node.js app with Nginx. App uses port 4100 for frontend and 3000 for backend. My frontend port 4100 works fine but I get an error for backend "'https://test.example.com/login' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint http://test.example.com:3000/api/users/login"

```
   location / {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4100;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
```

I am not sure how to rewrite this api in nginx. Can someone please help?
http://test.example.com:3000/api/users/login

```
   location /api/ {
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
   proxy_redirect     off;
   }
```

Comment: We'd need more information to help. Where does that message from from - the Nginx log? It looks like a browser message, but the browser doesn't talk to the back end directly. Please edit your post to include more context and to show more of the diagnostics you've done.

Comment: Yes, Thats the browser message. I modified  nginx.conf file to use port 443 to route requests to the application server on port 4100. How can I make the backend (port 3000) to respond to https requests?

Comment: Please edit your question to include more context and to show more of the diagnostics you've done